# Insert data into report viewer dynamically from code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have reportviewer control and want to insert data through c# code, how can i insert?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the Asp.Net ReportViewer controls, then there are is a whole load of [sample code you can take a look at on MSDN](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/reportviewer/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4940)